# SQL ORACLE Отделить буквы от цифр в строке

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите, каким образом можно отделить в строке буквенную часть от численной например есть чертеж СК-123 или М.123. Нужно отделить левую буквенную часть от правой численной что бы дальше я смогла отсортировать данные сначала по левой части (по алфавиту), затем после знака раз делителя сортировать по правой .

Comment: Разделители буквенной и численной части какие? то есть только точка или тире или и другие бывают? Всегда ли только по 1 блоку букв и цифр?

Answer (score 4):

Можете использовать функцию `ltrim( string1, [ trim_string ] )`, которая удаляет все перечисленные подстроки в `trim_string` из `string1`. Примеры использования:

```
SQL> SELECT LTRIM('123123.Ltrim123', '123.') FROM DUAL;
```

> LTRIM('123123LTRIM123','123')
>
> Ltrim123

```
SQL> SELECT LTRIM('xyxzyyy-Ltrim', 'xyz-') FROM DUAL;
```

> LTRIM('XYXZYYYLTRIM','XYZ')
>
> Ltrim

Также существует симметричная функция `rtrim`.

---

[Отсылка](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/ltrim.php)

Comment: Признаться, совсем не понимаю, как ваш ответ поможет решить поставленную задачу.

Comment: @lDrakonl, выделить буквенную часть из общей строки или цифры

Comment: Не понял. Поясните, как выделять любые наборы цифр или символов в универсальном случае?

Comment: @lDrakonl, для начала замечу, что ваш способ универсальный. Для выделения буквенной части: `rtrim(var,'.-1234567890')`

Comment: Хмм...не знал, что так можно. Думал, что удаляется именно последовательность целиком. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать с помощью регулярных выражений. Примерно так:

```
with s as (
  select 'СК-123' as s from dual
  union   all
  select 'М.123'  as s from dual
)
select regexp_substr(s,'[[:alpha:]]+') as symb,
       regexp_substr(s,'[[:digit:]]+') as num 
from   s
```